# Elements of order 2 in $(\mathbb{R}^*, \times)$

Tags: group-theory, smooth-manifolds

Tu's An Introduction to Manifolds, in question 15.9 asks a question about the center of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$. He claims it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^*$.

He then states that the group, $(\mathbb{R}^*, \times)$ has two elements of order $2$, which makes no sense to me as $-1$ is the only one I can find.

Can someone confirm I am correct so I can send an update for the errata?

Comment: What, precisely, does he say? In particular, does he say "two elements of order two" or "two elements $g$ such that $g^2=1$"?

Comment: He says, "The
group $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ has two elements of order 2, while the group $\{+-1\}\times\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ has four elements
of order 2.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or scan to your question?

Comment: I am skeptical as to this being an error or simply being a misreading on your part. Contacting the author about it is a last resort, which is why I am suggesting uploading a screenshot or scan so we can read precisely what is written for ourselves.

Comment: I quoted the exact text from the relevant section. I emailed the author, and he did say it was an error and that it should be order less than equal to 2 or elements $g$ such that $g^2=1$ as you wrote. Now maybe someone with more familiarity with groups may be able to infer intent from the broader context of the question.

Comment: Here is the full question for posterity, Show that the center of $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\times}$, corresponding to the subgroup of
scalar matrices, and that the center of $SL(2,\mathbb{R}) \times \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ is isomorphic to $\{\pm 1\} \times \mathbb{R}^{\times}$. The
group $\mathbb{R}^\times$ has two elements of order 2, while the group $\{\pm 1\} \times \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ has four elements
of order 2. Since their centers are not isomorphic, $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $SL(2,\mathbb{}R) \times \mathbb{R}^\times$ are not
isomorphic as groups.

Comment: @Jeff I believe that your correction about point (b) is now in the [official errata](https://ltu.pages.tufts.edu/doc/mf2_master_errata2.pdf) list. Not sure if it was you to notify the author. However, I've asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3962311/some-clarification-on-group-isomorphism-between-gln-mathbbr-and-sln-ma) another clarification for point (c).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, $\Bbb R^\times$ under multiplication has a single element of order $2$. In fact, if the number of order-$2$ elements in an abelian group is finite, then that number must be $2^n-1$ for some natural number $n$. So it *can't* be $2$.

Using my powers of mind reading, I induce that the author *might* have meant that there are two elements that are their own inverse, which is to say, two elements whose square is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

> **Theorem:** No group has exactly two elements of order two.

*Proof:* Suppose $G$ is a group with exactly two elements of order two. Call them $a$ and $b$. Consider $aba$. We have $$\begin{align}
(aba)^2&=(aba)(aba)\\
&=(ab)a^2(ba)\\
&=(ab)(ba)\\
&=ab^2a\\
&=a^2\\
&=e.
\end{align}$$

Thus $aba$ has order two (or $aba=e$, but that implies $b=a(aba)a=a^2=e$), so it must equal either $a$ or $b$.

Suppose the former. Then $aba=a$ implies $ab=e$, so $b^{-1}=a$. But the inverse of any order two element is the element itself.

Thus $aba=b$, which implies $ab=ba$. Now

$$\begin{align}
(ab)^2&=(ab)(ab)\\
&=(ab)(ba)\\
&=ab^2a\\
&=a^2\\
&=e.
\end{align}$$

Hence either $ab=a$ or $ab=b$. But the former implies $b=e$ has order one, whereas the latter implies $a=e$ has order one, which are contradictions.$\square$